# How to query cache when only some items are set?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I want to be able to read some items from cache.

I have 3 forms that ask a series of questions. At the end of each form, I cache the answers in Apollo cache before sending them to the server.

On the first form submit, I write to the cache like so:

```
client.cache.writeData({
  data: {
    listing: {
      boatType: this.state.boatType,
      title: this.state.title,
      price: this.state.price,
      city: this.state.city,
      __typename: "listing"
    }
  }
})
```

On the next page, I have a query that reads the cache:

```
<Query query={QUERY} errorPolicy="ignore">
  {({ data }) => (
        <Details 
        listing={data.listing}
    />
    )}
</Query>
```

My `QUERY` is as so:

```
gql`
  {
    listing @client {
      boatType
      title
      price
      city
      description
      make
      length
      maxPeople
      lifeJackets
      flares
      gps
      fishFinder
      skippered
      photos
    }
  }
`
```

which returns nothing but when I only query the items that have been set (like the query below), I get data returned.

```
gql`
  {
    listing @client {
      boatType
      title
      price
      city
    }
  }
`
```

Is there a way to use the full `QUERY` even before I have set the data?

Why does apollo not realise there is data in the cache for some fields and just return falsey for the other fields?

EDIT:

Adding client state:

// ApolloClient

```
return new ApolloClient({
  clientState: {
    defaults: {
      listing: {
        __typename: "lising",
        boatType: "",
        title: "",
        price: 0,
        city: "",
        description: "",
        make: "",
        length: 0,
        maxPeople: 0,
        lifeJackets: 0,
        flares: false,
        gps: false,
        fishFinder: false,
        skippered: false,
        photos: []
      }
    }
  },
  connectToDevTools: process.browser,
  ssrMode: !process.browser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
})
```

Comment: Are you initializing each property of `listing` with null (or some other value) when you configure the client?

Comment: @DanielRearden I have just added an edit to my post which includes my client initialisation. You can see what values are being initialised. Even when I don't initialise anything in the client, I get the same result.

Comment: The state should be initialized by calling `cache.writeData` as shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/#initializing-the-cache). That's the "old" way of setting defaults, prior to version 2.5. Not saying that's necessarily the root of your issue, but I don't think you're setting any defaults at the moment.

Comment: Have updated to initialise the cache as you mentioned and can see it is actually getting initialised now. If I hardcode the title in the cache to "Hello World", my query is now returning that. However, if I try write data from my first form and then read the cache, my new value is not returned.

Comment: Hmm, local state is... finicky. Writes to data won't be merged, so the other issue I see here is that you're doing a write with partial data. You should call `readQuery` to get the current data and then merge it yourself: `writeData({ data: { listing: { ...previousListing, city: 'New York', state: 'NY' } } })`

Comment: All of which should be extracted into a mutation as shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/#writedata)